# Java Thread and Exception?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm learning Java [threads tutorial](http://web.mit.edu/6.031/www/fa19/classes/19-concurrency/#@whether_that-s_more) and can't understand the explanation of last question 'Threads and exceptions':

> Now suppose we run this test:
>
> ```java
> @Test public void testThreadOops() {
>   new Thread(() -> { throw new Error("thread oops"); }).start();
> }
> ```
>
> Is a stack trace for `Error: thread oops` printed? ( ) Yes ( ) No
>
> The test: ( ) Passes    ( ) Fails

The explanation for this question is:

> The Error occurs on the newly-created thread, terminating that thread with a stack trace on the console. But the test method `testThreadOops` returns normally – there is no exception on the main thread – and the JUnit test passes. It does not detect the oops.

Why is there no exception in the main thread?

Comment: Answers given below are correct. Just want to add one thing to it. Since you're starting with threads, you might want to look at Callable interface and how it is different from Runnable. That'll give you more clarity about what's happening here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is a stack trace for Error: thread oops printed?

It depends.

An uncaught exception on a child thread (i.e. not the "main" thread) will be passed to the thread's uncaught exception handler, the threadgroup uncaught exception handler, or the default uncaught exception handler.  These would typically be responsible for printing a stacktrace.

If you (or your framework) don't set a handler, the default behavior is to do nothing, and there won't be a stacktace anywhere.

(The methods for setting handlers are described in the javadocs for `Thread`.)

> Why is there no exception in the main thread?

Because the exception is not thrown on the main thread.  It is thrown ... and must be caught / handled ... on the child thread's stack.

Think of it this way.  If an exception on a child thread was somehow rethrown on the parent thread, where would you catch it?  How would you deal with it?  What if it was a checked exception, and the context didn't allow that particular exception to be thrown?

Comment: *"If you (or your framework) don't set a handler, the default behavior is to do nothing, and there won't be a stacktace anywhere."* This is the opposite of what the linked tutorial says, but you seem to be correct and the tutorial is wrong - I did a quick test to confirm.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that I was correct.  I was going from my memory.  But I suspect that the actual default behavior is implementation specific.  It is not specified in the javadocs.

Comment: The default behaviour of doing nothing doesn't seem to be mentioned in the docs for `Thread`. The [`ThreadGroup` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException-java.lang.Thread-java.lang.Throwable-) say it prints a stack trace to stderr by default, and the [JLS (§11.13)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3) says *"the method uncaughtException is invoked for the ThreadGroup that is the parent of the current thread"*. So that seems to suggest the stack trace should be printed; I wonder what I'm missing.

Comment: You are correct.  Like I said in my previous comment the behavior when no handlers have been set is not specified by the javadocs.  It only says that when `getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` returns `null` that means that no (default) handler is called.

Comment: But it is easy to deal with this.  If you want a stacktrace when a child thread dies, either catch the exception in the thread's `run()` methd, or set an appropriate uncaught exception handler at the appropriate level.

Answer (score 3):

There is no exception thrown in the main thread simply because this code doesn't throw an exception in the main thread. It starts a new thread, and throws an exception in that new thread - not in the main thread.

When an exception is thrown (and not caught) in a thread, that thread terminates, but it doesn't "pass" the exception back to the "parent" thread that started it in the first place. If that happened, any thread which started other threads would continuously be at risk of stopping at any time because of an exception thrown in one of its "child" threads. If the "parent" thread were stopped half-way through some computation, it could leave some data in an invalid state.

Answer (score -1):

In the method below you are throwing an exception in the new thread you create not the main thread of the application. So no exception is thrown in the main thread.

```
new Thread(() -> { throw new Error("thread oops"); }).start();
```

Normally when an exception occurs in a thread it terminates itself instead of passing the exception in the main thread. This is to protect the main(parent thread) from stopping incase of child thread cause an exception.